# How to receive and send UDP package from network card ?

Tags: c#, network-programming

I need to write simple application that can send and receive some UDP package to the local network card. The UDP package contain some command ( some integer ) so i need to have the option to create the message that will be send over the UDP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`UdpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) class. You can define the message that is being send as a byte array. So you may want to use a [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) or [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) for serialization.

Comment: But how to send it to network card ? how can i detect the local network card ip address that can be use as the target address ? ?

Comment: You want to send to the localhost?

Comment: You can use `client.Send(data, data.Length, "localhost", port)`